# Getting string representation of Android java numeric constants / error code

Tags: java, android

Many Android java methods return numeric constant values. When logging or showing values to the user, I'd like to automatically convert these values to strings (something similar to Windows API `FormatMessage()`/`FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`). However, I couldn't find a way of doing it other than switching over all possible values and generating matching strings.

For example: `android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.onFailure()` returns an integer value: `ERROR` (0), `P2P_UNSUPPORTED` (1), `BUSY` (2). I'd like to convert the number to the appropriate string. I could write a switch case such as this:

```
public void onFailure(int reason) {
    String strReason;
    switch (reason) {
    case WifiP2pManager.BUSY: strReason = "BUSY"; break;
    case WifiP2pManager.ERROR: strReason = "ERROR"; break;
    case WifiP2pManager.P2P_UNSUPPORTED: strReason = "P2P_UNSUPPORTED"; break;
    default: strReason = Integer.toString(reason);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure failed, reason=" + strReason);            
}
```

But I'd like to avoid it, especially when there are more than 3 possible return values.

I tried searching a lot on StackExchange and other sites, but all results were related to integer parsing.

Any way of achieving what I try to do?

Comment: _"I could write a switch case such as this:"_ No you couldn't since Android does not support Java 7 (unless you are using Android KitKat)

Comment: I'm actually using Android KitKat and it indeed works... this doesn't work on previous versions? Interesting... (Java newbie)

Comment: @ZouZou Switches have been a feature in Java for a long time, you don't need Java 7 to use them.

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes Not switching on Strings. It has only been introduced since Java 7.

Comment: @ZouZou You're right, but in this case he's switching on an `int`, not a `string`, so Java 7 is still not required.

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes Oh yes you're right! I was pretty sure it was `switch (strReason)` -_-. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is simply non existent. You have no choice but to stick with the `switch` approach.

Comment: "No choice"?  Nobody here has heard of `HashMap`?

Comment: @ajb switch, hashmap, bugs bunny, it doesn't matter. He still has to come up with his own string representation and map them to an int, which is what he's trying to avoid.